# apache2 won't start

Tags: apache2, restart

I upgraded from ubuntu 10.04 server to ubuntu 12.04 server and things got messed up. After a while i got things to work. After a new installation of apache2 and mysql and phpmyadmin, apache2 won't start. This is the output I get when trying to start the service:

```
* Restarting web server apache2
Syntax error on line 161 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the   server configuration
```

Comment: Try working with your configs again, the error suggests you have an invalid line that was valid in 10.04 but not 12.04

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591543

Comment: can you tell us what that lin says?  'sudo nano -n /etc/apache2/apache2.conf'

Comment: I changed it is used to be :

   Files ~ "^\.ht">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy all
   </Files>
it says:
    <Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
    </Files>
 but now i get another error which is:
Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/apache.conf:
Invalid command 'DirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration